# Amazon RDS: Sudden increase in Read IOPS and Throughput

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds

I am using Amazon RDS to host the databases for my website. I am using the large instances for both my master and my read replica. Everything was running smoothly until suddenly the Read IOPS, Read Throughput and Queue Depth metrics in the AWS console started to increase suddenly (the blue instance is my master server, the orange one is the slave).

[image: Read IOPS]
[image: Read Throughput]
[image: Queue Depth]

At the time where this peak occured, no jobs with heavy workload or code changes were deployed. The CPU utilization according to the AWS console has increased slightly since that time. I am also running munin plugins to monitor my master server, and I see no changes in access or network throughput since that time. The open connections to the server (checked with `show processlist`) also stayed the same.

What is happening to my RDS instance? What could lead to this effect and how can I make this stop? And why doesn't this behaviour show up in munin?